SEO, Github repo not appearing in Google search results even after 6 months
I created a public repo EbaySharp 6 months ago, when I search by repo name "EbaySharp", I see my nuget package but I can't find github repo.
Is there anything special I need to do so it can be searched?
Repo can be seen here
https://github.com/CMS365-PTY-LTD/EbaySharp
I am not sure why this question got closed, the link which has been given to me is talking about general websites but my question is related to Github repository.
